# php popen(exim) from a webpage

Tags: popen, exim, apache2.4

Problem: Apache accessing programs in /usr/bin

Platform:
    Win/7 Pro Sp1
    Apache  2.4
    Php 5.6
    Cygwin emulator gives Linux/Unix emu and has
        Exim    4.84-1

program: sendit.php

```
hndl popen( exim ... )
    fwrite(hndle, email_headers);
    fwrite(hndle, email_body);
fflush(hndle);
fclose(hndle);
```

(a)launch from user account
    php sendit.php  -> exim/exim_main.log updated
        reports 368 bytes sent to exim
            -> email arrives

> > demonstrates sendit.php works & Exim config and permissions are correct

(b)launch from apache account  uid(apache) gid(srvc)
    php sendit.php  -> exim/exim_main.log updated
        reports 368 bytes sent to exim
            -> email arrives

> > demonstrates sendit.php runs from any account

(c)launch from within a web page
    Apache is run from its own uid/gid as in (b)

- page.phtml sendit.php 
  -> NO update to exim log
  -> no mail   recv'd
  reports same NNN bytes send to exim
  *NO* I/O errors
  *I* fwriting_stream 368 bytes ...
  *** wrote body fragment 368

  *** wrote total 368
  *I* Wrote Body:(368) of 368
  *I* Wrote EOT(5)   of 5
  *I* FLUSHING pipe
  *I* closing pipe
  *I* is closed pipe
  *I* returning 3

adding -d+deliver+host_lookup+lookup+rewrite options to the popen(), yields nice trace - -

EXCEPT when run withing Apache - - nothing shows up

Apache cfg has ExecCGI in the directory and other php / perl programs run there.
Issue is Exim is not within the Apache environment (/usr/bin/exim)

So, created link /usr/bin/exim -> docroot/exim
and reference this instance  popen(docroot/exim ...)

Still fails to deliver via pipe -> exim
Any ideas???

btw: have used popen in webpages several places with success
and yes, I verifed the popen return

```
$PIPE = popen( ... ...);if ($PIPE === false) die("*FE*);
```

Answer (score 0):

## STATUS: SOLVED 2015-05-30

Issue is Windows + Cygwin pathing

PHP tolerates Cygwin as $PATH is available.
Running within
Apache LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5.6/php5apache2_4.dll" does not

Must use an absolute WINDOWS path like
c:/cygwin/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe within the server.

php cmdPath_Tests.php

uses file_exists($path) exec to
find that path usable within Apache

Jeff@JeffPC7%
case 0 0 trying:
$ ls -l /usr/bin/exim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None 24 Apr 6 09:19 /usr/bin/exim -> /usr/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe

Jeff@JeffPC7%
$ ls -l /usr/bin/exim /cygwin/bin/exim{,-4.84-1}.exe c:/cygwin/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe
case 1 1
ls: cannot access /cygwin/bin/exim.exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /cygwin/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe: No such file or directory
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Administrator None 24 Apr 6 09:19 /usr/bin/exim -> /usr/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe

case 3 1 trying:
-rwxr-xr-x 3 Jeff None 1192467 Jan 25 19:16 c:/cygwin/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe

/usr/bin/exim
0 0 /usr/bin/exim

/usr/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe
0 1 /usr/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe

which: no exim-4.84-1.exe in (/cygwin/bin)
1 1 File Exists
cmd 1 1 trying: /cygwin/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe
results:

/usr/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe
2 1 trying: /usr/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe

*I* found:
3 1 trying: c:/cygwin/bin/exim-4.84-1.exe

 cmd results:
2015-05-30 11:58:24 NP6FDA-000530-QD Completed
ie: email sent